# Projects, Files, Services, Navigator color background

Tags: netbeans

In netbeans when we choose a profile in fonts & colors option screen that change editor windows background color but not one in project, files, service navigator.

[image]

like you can see in the picture

i'm the only one with this issue?

Edit seem  like impossible

[NetBeans, theme with black background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11585032/netbeans-theme-with-black-background)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using **Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors** will only affect the edit window. Changing the overall look and feel of NetBeans is done by changing the theme.

There are two dark themes that worked well on NetBeans 8.2, *Dark Metal* and *Dark Nimbus*, and they have been certified for NetBeans 10.0. You just have to ensure that the plugin for them is installed on NetBeans 10.0. To do that:

- Go to **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins**.
- Search under the **Names** column for **Dark Look and Feel**.
- Check that entry's **Install** check box, then click the **Install** button.
- Once the plugin has been installed NetBeans will invite you to restart.
- After restarting, go to **Tools > Options > Appearance** and select the **Look and Feel** tab. There should be two new entries at the bottom of the **Preferred Look and Feel** list: *Dark Metal* and *Dark Nimbus*.
- Select one of those entries and restart. In both cases all the NetBeans windows should now be dark.

This is what I get for *Dark Metal*:

[image: darkMetal]

And this is what I get for *Dark Nimbus*:

[image: darkNimbus]

Another option is to install and use the Darcula theme, [as detailed in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52697694/2985643). Although it is not certified for NetBeans 10.0 it seems to work fine. This shot shows the Darcula theme (**Tools > Options > Appearance > Look and Feel > Preferred look and feel > Darcula**), but with:

- The profile of the editor window overridden to *Norway Today* (**Tools > Options > Fonts & Colors > Profile > Norway Today**).
- The background color of the output window overridden to black (**Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Background Color > Black**).

[image: darcula]

Finally, third party sites provide further themes for NetBeans. For example:

- [NetBeans Themes](https://netbeansthemes.com/)
- [svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder](http://svenspruijt.nl/themebuilder/) - click the **Themes** button to list over 90 themes from various contributors.

Comment: Dark Look and Feel plugin is not available in Netbeans 10.0 (2019.Feb.18)

Comment: @mnesarco What do you mean by _"not available"_? If you go to **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins** in NetBeans 10.0 is there an entry named _"Dark Look and Feel Themes"_? If not then go to **Tools > Plugins > Settings** and ensure that the entry _"Latest Development Build"_ is checked, or do you not have that either?

Comment: "Dark Look and Feel Themes" does not appear in available plugins, and "Latest Development Build" does not appear in settings.

Comment: @mnesarco OK. Perhaps older downloads of NB10.0 did not include _"Latest Development Build"_, but when I downloaded it a few days ago it was there. However, you can add it manually: [1] Go to **Tools > Plugins > Settings** and click the **Add** button. [2] In the window that opens enter Name = `Latest Development Build`, URL = `http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz` and click **OK**. Then revisit the Available Plugins tab. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54729626/2985643) for more details of the process.

Comment: Thank you. I have downloaded it today and not included. But thanks to your comment I have added the missing update center and now I have all plugins.

Comment: @ OK. Thanks for the feedback on having to add `Latest Development Build`. I will research and update my answer above if necessary.

Comment: @skomisa you should really update your answer with the information about the develompent build, i also had to add it manually but almost did not read the comments you made to your own answer. Your comments solved the issue for me, it would have been fasterif they were part of the answer :)

Comment: I am using the snap package on Ubuntu 18.10, and dark plugins are not available and latest dev builds are not available - apache netbeans 11 - finally got those dark themes back  - thanks