# Apache Netbeans 10 CVS plugin not available?

Tags: java, netbeans, cvs, netbeans-10

i finally upgraded to Apache Netbeans 10 (from 8.2) and wanted to install the CVS plugin as usual using the menus `Tools->Plugins->Available Plugins`

However, i cannot seem to find/access the plugin. In Settings i activated the Netbeans 8.2 Plugin Portal, however i still have (after updating) only 31 Available Plugins and 9 Installed.

When i try to open a CVS versioned project, netbeans recognizes this and tries to automatically get CVS - but the download fails.

So, how can i install the CVS Plugin in Apache Netbeans 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Select **Tools > Plugins > Settings**
- Add the Update Center which includes the CVS plugin to the *Configuration of Update Centers* list:

  - Click the **Add** button to open the **Update Customizer Center** dialog.
  - In the **Name** field enter some descriptive value (e.g. **Latest Development Build**), and in the **URL** field enter this URL: `http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz`
  - Click **OK** to close the **Update Customizer Center** dialog, and return to the **Settings** tab.
- For that new entry named **Latest Development Build**, check its **Active** checkbox:

  [image: settings]
- Select **Tools > Plugins > Available Plugins**
- Enter ***CVS*** in the search field and the CVS plugin should be listed:

  [image: installCvsPlugin]
- Check the **Install** checkbox for the CVS plugin, click the **Install** button and follow the wizard's instructions.

After that you should be able to use CVS without needing to restart NetBeans:

- Select **Tools > Options > Team > Versioning** to configure CVS.
- Select a project in the **Projects** panel, right click and select **Versioning > Import into CVS Repository** to import a project into CVS.

Comment: The URL provided for Update Center gives a 403. Is there an updated URL we can use?

Comment: @quickblueblur I don't know why that is happening. I just tried that link and it worked fine. What happens if you just submit http://bits.netbeans.org/dev/nbms-and-javadoc/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/nbbuild/nbms/updates.xml.gz from your browser? It should download the *.gz file. Does that also fail with 403?

Comment: the browser gave me a 403. However, thanks to your comment, I figured it was the corporate network. Since it still worked for you I switched to our guest network and it worked fine.

Answer (score 6):

I worked off [the answer above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54729626) using NetBeans 12.3 and it worked well with the alternate plugin URL:

```
http://updates.netbeans.org/netbeans/updates/8.2/uc/final/certified/catalog.xml.gz
```

Instead of the `updates.xml.gz` URL in the linked answer.

Comment: Please don't post link-only answers. Explain how the link relates to the question and how it answers the question.

Comment: Note: at least as of Netbeans 12.5, this no longer seems to be working, either. Suggest trying the [manual download solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66921410/119114).

Answer (score 3):

The update center is no longer available. But you can still download the 3 needed plugins from the following links:

http://netbeans.apidesign.org/maven2/org/netbeans/modules/org-netbeans-modules-versioning-system-cvss/RELEASE701/org-netbeans-modules-versioning-system-cvss-RELEASE701.nbm

http://netbeans.apidesign.org/maven2/org/netbeans/api/org-jdesktop-layout/RELEASE802/org-jdesktop-layout-RELEASE802.nbm

http://netbeans.apidesign.org/maven2/org/netbeans/api/org-netbeans-lib-cvsclient/RELEASE712/org-netbeans-lib-cvsclient-RELEASE712.nbm

And install all of them together : **Select Tools > Plugins > Downloaded > Add plugins**

Screenshot prior to install:

[image]

Comment: For Java 14+ installation of the above plugins fails with "unpack200 not found". This is because this binary was removed in Java 14. Netbeans will allow you to select the binary from the bin/ folder of another Java 13 or lower installation.