# Disable multi-coloured braces in Netbeans 10.0

Tags: php, colors, netbeans-10

I have multi-coloured braces in Netbeans 10.0 and can't find a way of disabling them. They basically change colour for each nested level. I am aware of a plugin call Rainbow Braces but I don't seem to have it installed and I have the colour set to white (see image). Any ideas how to turn this off and have the braces the same colour as the text?

[image: Screenshot of Netbeans settings and showing coloured braces]

Comment: Could you double check that _Rainbow Braces_ is not installed?.... [1] **Tools > Plugins** [2] Click the **Installed** tab. If _Rainbow Braces_ is shown there then check the **Select** column for its entry, and then click **Uninstall** or **Deactivate** as desired. [3] If you don't see _Rainbow Braces_ on the **Installed** tab, check if it is listed on the **Available Plugins** tab instead. [4] How did you install Darcula? As far as I know it's not officially supported on NetBeans 10 (though it does seem to work OK).

Comment: Darcula plugin downloaded from here http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/62424/darcula-laf-for-netbeans and works fine. I reset my configuration and it looks like Rainbow Braces must have been installed because it appeared in the list of available plugins. It wasn't showing up under Installed Plugins though... anyway it is solved now

Comment: Ok, cool. Just FYI, there are also a couple of dark themes which are officially supported on NetBeans 10.0: _Dark Metal_ and _Dark Nimbus_. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/54413349/2985643 for details.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's a little late, but in my case I had to go to "Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Rainbow" and simply disable it.