# Does Netbeans support the Windows dark theme?

Tags: netbeans, themes, windows-themes

I've just updated Windows to version 1909 and I'm using the Dark theme. Now, I know there is a dark theme for Netbeans called 'Darcula' but I want to use the Microsoft dark theme. Does Netbeans support this theme?

Comment: Netbeans itself runs on java so it must be implementing its own *windows like* laf which may not follow the dark/light etc theme changes implemented in windows OS updates.Beside Darcula, try using newer IDEs like IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

> Does Netbeans support this theme...

No. If you select the "dark theme" in Windows it has no effect on NetBeans (though I was surprised to see that it did change the Firefox and Chrome browsers).

[Note that](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/5-dark-themes-windows-10/) "*The theme will change the Windows system apps and Microsoft’s store apps. You will still need to change other third-party apps on a case-by-case basis*".

> ...and if not at the moment will it be considered for future
>   implementation ?

Only the developers at NetBeans can answer that, but I strongly doubt it because:

- Setting the theme in NetBeans is not the same thing as the theme you describe for Windows. In fact, when you choose that so called "dark theme" in Windows you are actually choosing an option ("*Light*" or "*Dark*") for a field in the **Colors** screen labeled "*Choose your default app mode*". There is no "dark theme" option offered when you review the **Theme** options available with Windows 10.
- There would be no appetite for supporting a NetBeans plugin which was only relevant for the Windows platform.
- The provider of such a plugin would have no control or notice over unannounced changes made by Microsoft to their "dark plugin".

Also, note that Darcula is not the only dark theme available for NetBeans; [there are many others](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54413349/2985643).